# BadImageFormatException when using C++/CLI in a C# application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, c++-cli

I am currently developing an application in VS 2008, in which I have a unmanaged C++ library (A) that wraps up  two existing libraries (B + C) to simplify functionality. (A) has shown to work and I can successfully call and use it in a c++ test application.

The main purpose of (A) is to be used by a C# application, in order to do this I have followed the following link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/borisj/archive/2006/09/28/769708.aspx to create a CLI wrapper (D).

All seems well, everything compiles and I have attempted to test this in a simple C# application. I added a reference to (D) and fired up the program only to receive the BadImageFormatException when trying to use the class. From what I have read people suggest that there is a vesion mismatch in the DLLs somewhere, however I have built them all in Win32 to match each other.

In addition to this I have provided (D) and the C# application a copy of all the DLLs that are required but still seem to get a problem. I have noticed that a dll is not created for (D) when compiled which is my guess at why it is falling apart, however as I am new to this I don't know if it should or not.

Am I likely not including a DLL somewhere that I have overlooked that is causing this?

TLDR: A wraps  B + C, A is wrapped by D to be used in a C# application, but it hits and exception. (I have put all DLL where they should go (to my knowledge) and ensured they all match). Are there any gotchas that I may of missed?

Comment: To me this sounds like some dll's are compiled as 32bit dll's and some as 64bit dll's... or application is running as 64 bit process and trying to use 32bit dll's, or opposite... something like that.

Comment: 64b processes load correctly 32b images, but 32b processes cannot load 64b images.

Comment: @Gusman, that is not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change your compilation mode to x86 or Any CPU Mode.

Right Button click in your solution > Configuration Manager.

**Or**

Build > Configuration Manager

[image]

In the Configuration Manager change all projects to compile in x86 or ANy CPU, try both.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the problem seemed to go further down in the external libraries, did what you suggested on all dependencies.

Comment: You need to change the Platform only for the EXE to "x86"!

Answer (score 1):

To the people who are experiencing `BadImageFormatException` in this same context in 2022:

For me the problem was solved by disabling "Prefer 32 bits" from C# library properties.